# Basic counter display sometimes stops short

Tags: java, android

I have two text fields that I want to show counting up and stopping at a certain number.  Typically it works fine, but sometimes one or both stop short by one number.

```
final TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
final TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
winthread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    float store_count = oldstore;
    int counter = 0;
    public void run() {
        while (counter < final_value) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  }
            t1.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    t1.setText(String.format("T1 $%.2f", store_count));
                }
            });
            t2.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    t2.setText(String.format("T2 %d", counter));
                }
            });
            counter++;
            store_count = oldstore +  counter * 5;
        }
    }
});
winthread.start();
```

From the code, T1 should stop at *oldstore+final_valuex5* and T2 should stop at *final_value* but sometimes T1 stops at *oldstore+final_valuex5-1* or T2 stops at *final_value-1*

Comment: Whatever the actual variable is in the while loop - by definition of your loop it will terminate when `counter` is at final which means you'll never see the value in t2 at final - for example.

Comment: yeah, it should be "final_value", i edited.  Hmm, you're right, it should stop t2 = final -1, I'll look at the code again to see whats going on.  Either way, whatever happens, it should be consistent and not sometimes be one less.  I was thinking perhaps there was some odd behavior with the thread and the text field updates

Comment: ok this is strange.  If I put a breakpoint at the while loop, T2 is always displayed as Counter + 1 eventhough the "setText" is before "counter++".  If I put a breakpoint at "counter++", T2 displays counter.  Is the setText executing AFTER counter++ because of threading?

Comment: I just moved counter++ and the line after it to before the setText and it seems to work better now.

Comment: The only UI behavior that may seem odd that I can tell is it may appear to "skip" values because you are queueing a new value every 100 milliseconds to the UI queue and you may not be able to see those changes for a variety of reasons.

Comment: And referring to `counter` post delayed may be an issue as well - try forming the string before `post`ing - so it uses the value at the iteration of the loop.